# How to generate user friendly message based on icalendar format

Tags: c#, .net, icalendar

Lets say we have recurrence rule like this one:

`RRULE:FREQ=MONTHLY;BYDAY=-2FR;COUNT=7`

My question is how to generate user friendly text from `RRULE` like this: 
every month on the 2nd last Friday for 7 times

Are there any `.net c#` libs, which allow to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [one](https://github.com/EWSoftware/PDI) helped me. **EWSoftware.PDI** library contains `Recurrence` class with `ToDescription` method, which generates plain text description based on provided `RRULE`.

```
var recurrence = new Recurrence("FREQ=MONTHLY;BYDAY=-2FR;COUNT=7")
{
    StartDateTime = startDate
};

var description = recurrence.ToDescription();
```

**Output**: `Recur every month on the 2nd last Friday for 7 times`

Answer (score 1):

Another lightweight solution, based on [rrule.js](https://github.com/jakubroztocil/rrule) - I translated their friendly string converter to C# in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/paviad/0d1f668764195c42d26d1582769419ee)

(gist content provided literally at end of answer, just in case link is broken)

(English only version)

### Usage (in test form):

```cs
var rp = new Ical.Net.DataTypes.RecurrencePattern(FrequencyType.Daily) {
    ByHour = {
        2,
        16,
    },
    ByMinute = { 0 },
    BySecond = { 0 },
};

var toText = new ToText(rp);

var friendlyName = toText.ToFriendlyName();

Assert.Equal("Every day at 2 and 16", friendlyName);
```

### Gist content (as of July 3rd 2023)

```js
using Ical.Net;
using Ical.Net.DataTypes;

public class ToText {
    private static readonly string[] MonthNames = {
        "January",
        "February",
        "March",
        "April",
        "May",
        "June",
        "July",
        "August",
        "September",
        "October",
        "November",
        "December",
    };

    private readonly List<int>? _byMonthDay;
    private readonly ByWeekDayRec? _byWeekDay;
    private readonly Func<DateTime, string> _dateFormatter;
    private readonly RecurrencePattern _recurrencePattern;
    private readonly List<string> _text = new();

    public ToText(RecurrencePattern recurrencePattern, Func<DateTime, string>? dateFormatter = null) {
        _recurrencePattern = recurrencePattern;
        _dateFormatter = dateFormatter ?? DefaultDateFormatter;

        DayOfWeek[] weekdays = {
            DayOfWeek.Sunday, DayOfWeek.Monday, DayOfWeek.Tuesday, DayOfWeek.Wednesday, DayOfWeek.Thursday,
        };

        DayOfWeek[] weekend = { DayOfWeek.Friday, DayOfWeek.Saturday };

        bool Contains(DayOfWeek d) => _recurrencePattern.ByDay.Any(z => z.DayOfWeek == d);
        bool NContains(DayOfWeek d) => _recurrencePattern.ByDay.All(z => z.DayOfWeek != d);

        if (_recurrencePattern.ByDay.Count > 0) {
            var allWeeks = _recurrencePattern.ByDay.Where(r => r.Offset == 0).ToList();
            var someWeeks = _recurrencePattern.ByDay.Where(r => r.Offset != 0).ToList();
            var isWeekDays = weekdays.All(Contains) && weekend.All(NContains);
            var isEveryDay = weekdays.All(Contains) && weekend.All(Contains);
            _byWeekDay = new ByWeekDayRec(allWeeks, someWeeks, isWeekDays, isEveryDay);
        }

        if (_recurrencePattern.ByMonthDay.Count > 0) {
            var positive = _recurrencePattern.ByMonthDay.Where(r => r > 0).Order().ToList();
            var negative = _recurrencePattern.ByMonthDay.Where(r => r < 0).Order().ToList();
            _byMonthDay = positive.Concat(negative).ToList();
        }
    }

    public string ToFriendlyName() {
        _text.Add("Every");

        switch (_recurrencePattern.Frequency) {
            case FrequencyType.Minutely:
                Minutely();
                break;
            case FrequencyType.Hourly:
                Hourly();
                break;
            case FrequencyType.Daily:
                Daily();
                break;
            case FrequencyType.Weekly:
                Weekly();
                break;
            case FrequencyType.Monthly:
                Monthly();
                break;
            case FrequencyType.Yearly:
                Yearly();
                break;
            case FrequencyType.Secondly:
            case FrequencyType.None:
            default:
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        }

        if (_recurrencePattern.Until != DateTime.MinValue) {
            _text.Add("until");
            var until = _recurrencePattern.Until;
            _text.Add(_dateFormatter(until));
        }
        else if (_recurrencePattern.Count > 0) {
            _text.Add("for");
            _text.Add(_recurrencePattern.Count.ToString());
            _text.Add(Plural(_recurrencePattern.Count) ? "times" : "time");
        }

        if (!IsFullyConvertible()) {
            _text.Add("(~ approximate)");
        }

        return string.Join(' ', _text);
    }

    private static string DefaultDateFormatter(DateTime d) {
        var utc = d.ToUniversalTime();
        var year = utc.Year;
        var month = MonthNames[utc.Month];
        var day = utc.Day;

        return $"{month} ${day}, ${year}";
    }

    private static string List<T>(IEnumerable<T> arr, Func<T, string> getText, string? finalDelim = null,
        string delim = ",") {
        static string DelimJoin(IReadOnlyList<string> array, string delimiter, string finalDelimiter) {
            var list = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < array.Count; i++) {
                if (i != 0) {
                    if (i == array.Count - 1) {
                        list += $" {finalDelimiter} ";
                    }
                    else {
                        list += $"{delimiter} ";
                    }
                }

                list += array[i];
            }

            return list;
        }

        var strarr = arr.Select(getText).DefaultIfEmpty("").ToList();
        if (finalDelim is not null) {
            return DelimJoin(strarr, delim, finalDelim);
        }

        return strarr.Aggregate((x, y) => $"{x}{delim} {y}");
    }

    private static string MonthText(int m) {
        return MonthNames[m - 1];
    }

    private static string Nth(int n) {
        if (n == -1) {
            return "last";
        }

        var npos = Math.Abs(n);
        var nth = npos switch {
            1 => npos + "st",
            2 => npos + "nd",
            3 => npos + "rd",
            21 => npos + "st",
            22 => npos + "nd",
            23 => npos + "rd",
            31 => npos + "st",
            _ => npos + "th",
        };

        return n < 0 ? nth + " " + "last" : nth;
    }

    private static bool Plural(int n) => n % 100 != 1;

    private static string WeekDayText(WeekDay r) => r.DayOfWeek.ToString();

    private void ByHour() {
        _text.Add("at");
        _text.Add(List(_recurrencePattern.ByHour, x => x.ToString(), "and"));
    }

    private void ByMonth() {
        _text.Add(List(_recurrencePattern.ByMonth, MonthText, "and"));
    }

    private void ByMonthDay() {
        if (_byWeekDay is { AllWeeks.Count: > 0 }) {
            _text.Add("on");
            _text.Add(List(_byWeekDay.AllWeeks, WeekDayText, "or"));
            _text.Add("the");
            _text.Add(List(_byMonthDay!, Nth, "or"));
        }
        else {
            _text.Add("on the");
            _text.Add(List(_byMonthDay!, Nth, "and"));
        }
    }

    private void ByWeekDay() {
        if (_byWeekDay is { AllWeeks.Count: > 0, IsWeekDays: false }) {
            _text.Add("on");
            _text.Add(List(_byWeekDay.AllWeeks, WeekDayText));
        }

        if (_byWeekDay is { SomeWeeks.Count: > 0 }) {
            if (_byWeekDay is { AllWeeks.Count: > 0 }) {
                _text.Add("and");
            }

            _text.Add("on the");
            List(_byWeekDay.SomeWeeks, WeekDayText, "and");
        }
    }

    private void Daily() {
        if (_recurrencePattern.Interval != 1) {
            _text.Add(_recurrencePattern.Interval.ToString());
        }

        if (_byWeekDay is { IsWeekDays: true }) {
            _text.Add(Plural(_recurrencePattern.Interval) ? "weekdays" : "weekday");
        }
        else {
            _text.Add(Plural(_recurrencePattern.Interval) ? "days" : "day");
        }

        if (_recurrencePattern.ByMonth.Count > 0) {
            _text.Add("in");
            ByMonth();
        }

        if (_byMonthDay is not null) {
            ByMonthDay();
        }
        else if (_byWeekDay is not null) {
            ByWeekDay();
        }
        else if (_recurrencePattern.ByHour.Count > 0) {
            ByHour();
        }
    }

    private void Hourly() {
        if (_recurrencePattern.Interval != 1) {
            _text.Add(_recurrencePattern.Interval.ToString());
        }

        _text.Add(Plural(_recurrencePattern.Interval) ? "hours" : "hour");
    }

    private bool IsFullyConvertible() {
        if (_recurrencePattern.Frequency switch {
                FrequencyType.None => true,
                FrequencyType.Secondly => true,
                _ => false,
            }) {
            return false;
        }

        if (_recurrencePattern.Until != DateTime.MinValue && _recurrencePattern.Count > 0) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    private void Minutely() {
        if (_recurrencePattern.Interval != 1) {
            _text.Add(_recurrencePattern.Interval.ToString());
        }

        _text.Add(Plural(_recurrencePattern.Interval) ? "minutes" : "minute");
    }

    private void Monthly() {
        if (_recurrencePattern.ByMonth.Count > 0) {
            if (_recurrencePattern.Interval != 1) {
                _text.Add(_recurrencePattern.Interval.ToString());
                _text.Add("months");
                if (Plural(_recurrencePattern.Interval)) {
                    _text.Add("in");
                }
            }

            ByMonth();
        }
        else {
            if (_recurrencePattern.Interval != 1) {
                _text.Add(_recurrencePattern.Interval.ToString());
            }

            _text.Add(Plural(_recurrencePattern.Interval) ? "months" : "month");
        }

        if (_byMonthDay is not null) {
            ByMonthDay();
        }
        else if (_byWeekDay is { IsWeekDays: true }) {
            _text.Add("on");
            _text.Add("weekdays");
        }
        else {
            ByWeekDay();
        }
    }

    private void Weekly() {
        if (_recurrencePattern.Interval != 1) {
            _text.Add(_recurrencePattern.Interval.ToString());
            _text.Add(Plural(_recurrencePattern.Interval) ? "weeks" : "week");
        }

        if (_byWeekDay is { IsWeekDays: true }) {
            if (_recurrencePattern.Interval == 1) {
                _text.Add(Plural(_recurrencePattern.Interval) ? "weekdays" : "weekday");
            }
            else {
                _text.Add("on");
                _text.Add("weekdays");
            }
        }
        else if (_byWeekDay is { IsEveryDay: true }) {
            _text.Add(Plural(_recurrencePattern.Interval) ? "days" : "day");
        }
        else {
            if (_recurrencePattern.Interval == 1) {
                _text.Add("week");
            }

            if (_recurrencePattern.ByMonth.Count > 0) {
                _text.Add("in");
                ByMonth();
            }

            if (_byMonthDay is not null) {
                ByMonthDay();
            }
            else if (_byWeekDay is not null) {
                ByWeekDay();
            }
        }
    }

    private void Yearly() {
        if (_recurrencePattern.ByMonth.Count > 0) {
            if (_recurrencePattern.Interval != 1) {
                _text.Add(_recurrencePattern.Interval.ToString());
                _text.Add("years");
            }

            ByMonth();
        }
        else {
            if (_recurrencePattern.Interval != 1) {
                _text.Add(_recurrencePattern.Interval.ToString());
            }

            _text.Add(Plural(_recurrencePattern.Interval) ? "years" : "year");
        }

        if (_byMonthDay is not null) {
            ByMonthDay();
        }
        else if (_byWeekDay is not null) {
            ByWeekDay();
        }

        if (_recurrencePattern.ByYearDay.Count > 0) {
            _text.Add("on the");
            _text.Add(List(_recurrencePattern.ByYearDay, Nth, "and"));
            _text.Add("day");
        }

        if (_recurrencePattern.ByWeekNo.Count > 0) {
            _text.Add("in");
            _text.Add(Plural(_recurrencePattern.ByWeekNo.Count) ? "weeks" : "week");
            _text.Add(List(_recurrencePattern.ByWeekNo, x => x.ToString(), "and"));
        }
    }

    private record ByWeekDayRec(List<WeekDay> AllWeeks, List<WeekDay> SomeWeeks, bool IsWeekDays, bool IsEveryDay);
}
```

Comment: You are a lifesaver, I was just about to do the same and someone beat me to it.

Comment: I spoke too soon. This gist unfortunately doesn't work too well. Using an RRULE string of "FREQ=WEEKLY;BYDAY=MO,TU,WE,TH,FR" results in "Every week on the". Whereas, the rrule.js library produces "every weekday"

Comment: Looks like the issue from my testing is the weekdays[] and weekend[] values are wrong. Maybe this was done to work around a bug in ICal, but should be corrected to use the proper weekdays/weekend values.

Comment: Sounds like a culture issue. Israel for example has sunday-thursday as weekdays.

Answer (score 0):

Added an updated version of Aviad P.'s answer which produces the exact same output as [rrule.js](https://github.com/jakubroztocil/rrule) - his answer unfortunately has a lot of bugs and doesn't really work but was 95% of the way there, so I wrote a bunch of tests to ensure the results are exactly the same as the rrule js library.

Usage:

```
var rrule = "RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=30;WKST=MO;BYDAY=TU,WE;BYMONTH=2,10";
var recurrenceRule = new RecurrencePattern(rrule);
var text = recurrenceRule.ToFriendlyString();

Assert.Equal("every day in February and October on Tuesday, Wednesday for 30 times", friendlyName);
```

Source:

```
public static class ICalExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interpret a recurrence (RRule) pattern to a human readable string
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="recurrencePattern"></param>
    /// <param name="dateFormatter"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string ToFriendlyString(this RecurrencePattern recurrencePattern, Func<DateTime, string>? dateFormatter = null)
    {
        return new ToText(recurrencePattern, dateFormatter).ToFriendlyName();
    }
}

// this is a direct port of rrule.js behavior of the ToText() class.
// https://github.com/jkbrzt/rrule/blob/master/src/nlp/totext.ts
// partial credit to (but doesn't work right): https://gist.github.com/paviad/0d1f668764195c42d26d1582769419ee
public class ToText
{
    private static readonly string[] MonthNames = {
        "January",
        "February",
        "March",
        "April",
        "May",
        "June",
        "July",
        "August",
        "September",
        "October",
        "November",
        "December",
    };

    private readonly List<int>? _byMonthDay;
    private readonly ByWeekDayRec? _byWeekDay;
    private readonly Func<DateTime, string> _dateFormatter;
    private readonly RecurrencePattern _recurrencePattern;
    private readonly List<string> _text = new();

    public ToText(RecurrencePattern recurrencePattern, Func<DateTime, string>? dateFormatter = null)
    {
        _recurrencePattern = recurrencePattern;
        _dateFormatter = dateFormatter ?? DefaultDateFormatter;

        DayOfWeek[] weekdays = { DayOfWeek.Monday, DayOfWeek.Tuesday, DayOfWeek.Wednesday, DayOfWeek.Thursday, DayOfWeek.Friday };
        DayOfWeek[] weekend = { DayOfWeek.Saturday, DayOfWeek.Sunday };

        bool Contains(DayOfWeek d) => _recurrencePattern.ByDay.Any(z => z.DayOfWeek == d);
        bool NContains(DayOfWeek d) => _recurrencePattern.ByDay.All(z => z.DayOfWeek != d);

        if (_recurrencePattern.ByMonthDay.Count > 0)
        {
            var positive = _recurrencePattern.ByMonthDay.Where(r => r > 0).Order().ToList();
            var negative = _recurrencePattern.ByMonthDay.Where(r => r < 0).Order().ToList();
            _byMonthDay = positive.Concat(negative).ToList();
        }

        if (_recurrencePattern.ByDay.Count > 0)
        {
            var allWeeks = _recurrencePattern.ByDay.Where(r => r.Offset == int.MinValue).ToList();
            var someWeeks = _recurrencePattern.ByDay.Where(r => r.Offset != int.MinValue).ToList();
            var isWeekDays = weekdays.All(Contains) && weekend.All(NContains);
            var isEveryDay = weekdays.All(Contains) && weekend.All(Contains);
            _byWeekDay = new ByWeekDayRec(allWeeks, someWeeks, isWeekDays, isEveryDay);
        }
    }

    public string ToFriendlyName()
    {
        _text.Add("every");

        switch (_recurrencePattern.Frequency)
        {
            case FrequencyType.Minutely:
                Minutely();
                break;
            case FrequencyType.Hourly:
                Hourly();
                break;
            case FrequencyType.Daily:
                Daily();
                break;
            case FrequencyType.Weekly:
                Weekly();
                break;
            case FrequencyType.Monthly:
                Monthly();
                break;
            case FrequencyType.Yearly:
                Yearly();
                break;
            case FrequencyType.Secondly:
            case FrequencyType.None:
            default:
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        }

        if (_recurrencePattern.Until != DateTime.MinValue)
        {
            _text.Add("until");
            var until = _recurrencePattern.Until;
            _text.Add(_dateFormatter(until));
        }
        else if (_recurrencePattern.Count > 0)
        {
            _text.Add("for");
            _text.Add(_recurrencePattern.Count.ToString());
            _text.Add(Plural(_recurrencePattern.Count) ? "times" : "time");
        }

        if (!IsFullyConvertible())
        {
            _text.Add("(~ approximate)");
        }

        return string.Join(' ', _text);
    }

    private static string DefaultDateFormatter(DateTime d)
    {
        var year = d.Year;
        var month = MonthNames[d.Month - 1];
        var day = d.Day;

        return $"{month} {day}, {year}";
    }

    private static string List<T>(IEnumerable<T> arr, Func<T, string> getText, string? finalDelim = null, string delim = ",")
    {
        static string DelimJoin(IReadOnlyList<string> array, string delimiter, string finalDelimiter)
        {
            var list = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < array.Count; i++)
            {
                if (i != 0)
                {
                    if (i == array.Count - 1)
                    {
                        list += $" {finalDelimiter} ";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        list += $"{delimiter} ";
                    }
                }

                list += array[i];
            }

            return list;
        }

        var strarr = arr.Select(getText).DefaultIfEmpty("").ToList();
        if (finalDelim is not null)
        {
            return DelimJoin(strarr, delim, finalDelim);
        }

        return strarr.Aggregate((x, y) => $"{x}{delim} {y}");
    }

    private static string MonthText(int m)
    {
        return MonthNames[m - 1];
    }

    private static string Nth(int n)
    {
        if (n == -1)
        {
            return "last";
        }

        var npos = Math.Abs(n);
        var nth = npos switch
        {
            1 => npos + "st",
            2 => npos + "nd",
            3 => npos + "rd",
            21 => npos + "st",
            22 => npos + "nd",
            23 => npos + "rd",
            31 => npos + "st",
            _ => npos + "th",
        };

        return n < 0 ? nth + " " + "last" : nth;
    }

    private static bool Plural(int n) => n % 100 != 1;

    private static string WeekDayText(WeekDay wday)
    {
        var isNum = false;
        var weekday = isNum ? (int)wday.DayOfWeek % 7 : (int)wday.DayOfWeek;
        
        var r = wday.Offset != int.MinValue ? Nth(wday.Offset) + " " : "";
        return r + wday.DayOfWeek;
    }

    private void ByHour()
    {
        _text.Add("at");
        _text.Add(List(_recurrencePattern.ByHour, x => x.ToString(), "and"));
    }

    private void ByMonth()
    {
        _text.Add(List(_recurrencePattern.ByMonth, MonthText, "and"));
    }

    private void ByMonthDay()
    {
        if (_byWeekDay is { AllWeeks.Count: > 0 })
        {
            _text.Add("on");
            _text.Add(List(_byWeekDay.AllWeeks, WeekDayText, "or"));
            _text.Add("the");
            _text.Add(List(_byMonthDay!, Nth, "or"));
        }
        else
        {
            _text.Add("on the");
            _text.Add(List(_byMonthDay!, Nth, "and"));
        }
    }

    private void ByWeekDay()
    {
        if (_byWeekDay is { AllWeeks.Count: > 0, IsWeekDays: false })
        {
            _text.Add("on");
            _text.Add(List(_byWeekDay.AllWeeks, WeekDayText));
        }

        if (_byWeekDay is { SomeWeeks.Count: > 0 })
        {
            if (_byWeekDay is { AllWeeks.Count: > 0 })
            {
                _text.Add("and");
            }

            _text.Add("on the");
            _text.Add(List(_byWeekDay.SomeWeeks, WeekDayText, "and"));
        }
    }

    private void Daily()
    {
        if (_recurrencePattern.Interval != 1)
        {
            _text.Add(_recurrencePattern.Interval.ToString());
        }

        if (_byWeekDay is { IsWeekDays: true })
        {
            _text.Add(Plural(_recurrencePattern.Interval) ? "weekdays" : "weekday");
        }
        else
        {
            _text.Add(Plural(_recurrencePattern.Interval) ? "days" : "day");
        }

        if (_recurrencePattern.ByMonth.Count > 0)
        {
            _text.Add("in");
            ByMonth();
        }

        if (_byMonthDay is not null)
        {
            ByMonthDay();
        }
        else if (_byWeekDay is not null)
        {
            ByWeekDay();
        }
        else if (_recurrencePattern.ByHour.Count > 0)
        {
            ByHour();
        }
    }

    private void Hourly()
    {
        if (_recurrencePattern.Interval != 1)
        {
            _text.Add(_recurrencePattern.Interval.ToString());
        }

        _text.Add(Plural(_recurrencePattern.Interval) ? "hours" : "hour");
    }

    private bool IsFullyConvertible()
    {
        if (_recurrencePattern.Frequency switch
        {
            FrequencyType.None => true,
            FrequencyType.Secondly => true,
            _ => false,
        })
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (_recurrencePattern.Until != DateTime.MinValue && _recurrencePattern.Count > 0)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    private void Minutely()
    {
        if (_recurrencePattern.Interval != 1)
        {
            _text.Add(_recurrencePattern.Interval.ToString());
        }

        _text.Add(Plural(_recurrencePattern.Interval) ? "minutes" : "minute");
    }

    private void Monthly()
    {
        if (_recurrencePattern.ByMonth.Count > 0)
        {
            if (_recurrencePattern.Interval != 1)
            {
                _text.Add(_recurrencePattern.Interval.ToString());
                _text.Add("months");
                if (Plural(_recurrencePattern.Interval))
                {
                    _text.Add("in");
                }
            }

            ByMonth();
        }
        else
        {
            if (_recurrencePattern.Interval != 1)
            {
                _text.Add(_recurrencePattern.Interval.ToString());
            }

            _text.Add(Plural(_recurrencePattern.Interval) ? "months" : "month");
        }

        if (_byMonthDay is not null)
        {
            ByMonthDay();
        }
        else if (_byWeekDay is { IsWeekDays: true })
        {
            _text.Add("on");
            _text.Add("weekdays");
        }
        else
        {
            ByWeekDay();
        }
    }

    private void Weekly()
    {
        if (_recurrencePattern.Interval != 1)
        {
            _text.Add(_recurrencePattern.Interval.ToString());
            _text.Add(Plural(_recurrencePattern.Interval) ? "weeks" : "week");
        }

        if (_byWeekDay is { IsWeekDays: true })
        {
            if (_recurrencePattern.Interval == 1)
            {
                _text.Add(Plural(_recurrencePattern.Interval) ? "weekdays" : "weekday");
            }
            else
            {
                _text.Add("on");
                _text.Add("weekdays");
            }
        }
        else if (_byWeekDay is { IsEveryDay: true })
        {
            _text.Add(Plural(_recurrencePattern.Interval) ? "days" : "day");
        }
        else
        {
            if (_recurrencePattern.Interval == 1)
            {
                _text.Add("week");
            }

            if (_recurrencePattern.ByMonth.Count > 0)
            {
                _text.Add("in");
                ByMonth();
            }

            if (_byMonthDay is not null)
            {
                ByMonthDay();
            }
            else if (_byWeekDay is not null)
            {
                ByWeekDay();
            }
        }
    }

    private void Yearly()
    {
        if (_recurrencePattern.ByMonth.Count > 0)
        {
            if (_recurrencePattern.Interval != 1)
            {
                _text.Add(_recurrencePattern.Interval.ToString());
                _text.Add("years");
            }

            ByMonth();
        }
        else
        {
            if (_recurrencePattern.Interval != 1)
            {
                _text.Add(_recurrencePattern.Interval.ToString());
            }

            _text.Add(Plural(_recurrencePattern.Interval) ? "years" : "year");
        }

        if (_byMonthDay is not null)
        {
            ByMonthDay();
        }
        else if (_byWeekDay is not null)
        {
            ByWeekDay();
        }

        if (_recurrencePattern.ByYearDay.Count > 0)
        {
            _text.Add("on the");
            _text.Add(List(_recurrencePattern.ByYearDay, Nth, "and"));
            _text.Add("day");
        }

        if (_recurrencePattern.ByWeekNo.Count > 0)
        {
            _text.Add("in");
            _text.Add(Plural(_recurrencePattern.ByWeekNo.Count) ? "weeks" : "week");
            _text.Add(List(_recurrencePattern.ByWeekNo, x => x.ToString(), "and"));
        }
    }

    private record ByWeekDayRec(List<WeekDay> AllWeeks, List<WeekDay> SomeWeeks, bool IsWeekDays, bool IsEveryDay);
}
```